# In a matrix put 0 in the row and column of a cell which contains 0 without using extra space

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, matrix

Given a matrix, if a cell contains 0, then we have make entire row and column corresponding to the cell as 0. For example, if

```
      1 2 3
M  =  0 4 5
      4 2 0
```

then the output should be

```
      0 2 0
      0 0 0
      0 0 0
```

The method I thought is as follows

1. Make auxiliary arrays `row[]` and `col[]`. If a cell(i,j) contains 0 then, mark `row[i]` and `col[j]` as 0.(Initially `row[]` and `col[]` contains all 1s).
2. Again traverse the whole matrix, if for cell(i,j), either of `row[i]` or `col[j]` is 0, then put cell(i,j) as 0.

This takes O(m*n) time and O(m+n) space.

How to optimize it further specially in terms of space.Any suggestions for improving time complexity are also welcomed.

Comment: Are there sentinel values available (values that are not possible valid entries in the matrix)? If so, you can make a pass that changes all values that should be changed to zero to the sentinel values (leave any actual zeros alone on the first pass). Then make a second pass through the matrix changing sentinel values to zero. No extra  space needed.

Comment: There are no sentinel values

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aha, this is an old question.

1. Use one boolean variate(`isZeroInFirstRow`) saving if first row has zero element(s) or not and one boolean variate(`isZeroInFirstCol`) saving if first column has zero element(s) or not.
2. Then, traverse the whole matrix. If `cell(i,j)==0`, then set cell(0,j) and cell(i,0) to 0.
3. Traverse the first row of the matrix. If `cell(0,j)==0`, then set all elements in column(j) to 0.
4. Traverse the first column of the matrix. If `cell(i,0)==0`, then set all elements in row(i) to 0.
5. If `isZeroInFirstRow==true`, set all elements in row(0) to 0.
6. If `isZeroInFirstCol==true`, set all elements in column(0) to 0.

Comment: When you reach steps 5 and 6, you will have zeroes in 1st row and 1st column (from steps 2 and 3) even if they didn't have any zero initially.

Comment: Your answer can be corrected by moving steps 5 and 6 to the beginning and then keeping two boolean variables to store whether to change row[0] and column[0] in the end.

Comment: re @AbhishekBansal : you're right. "if it has zero" actually means it has zero(s) before step 2. I edited my answer to make it more precisely.

Comment: What if the two boolean variables are false? You did not store the original values of first row and first column and your values are overwritten in step 3 and 4. How will you get the original values of first row and first column back?

Comment: @SuperCoder  Not necessary. The cell(0,j) (for example) which you have overwritten to 0 because there is zero in cell(x, j). It should be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in O(1) space. One solution is to iterate on the matrix, for each 0 you see, you fill the corresponding row/col with some character, 'X' for example.

When you finish, you should have something like that:

```
    X 2 X
M=  0 X X
    X X 0
```

Then you iterate again on the matrix and replace each 'X' with 0 to get:

```
    0 2 0
M=  0 0 0
    0 0 0
```

Comment: How can you put character X if it is an integer array and there are no sentinel values.

Comment: @SuperCoder You didn't mention there can't be sentinel values in the question. Edit it.

Comment: you can put a sentinal value , say -INF , which is not present in matrix .

Comment: @anon Only if you use floating point. OP mentioned there are NO sentinel values.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned with storage you may think of using some sparse matrix [storage formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) to store the resulting matrix, and then free the original dense input.

An example of what I am proposing may be the following (implementing COO format) which should take O(M*N) time:

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstddef>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    constexpr size_t M = 3;
    constexpr size_t N = 3;
    int matrix[M][N] = {
        {1, 2, 3},
        {0, 4, 5},
        {4, 2, 0}
    };    

    vector<size_t> markedRows;
    vector<size_t> markedColumns;
    // Search for zeroes
    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < M; ++ii) {
        for(size_t jj = 0; jj < N; ++jj) {
            if (matrix[ii][jj] == 0) {
                markedRows.push_back   (ii);
                markedColumns.push_back(jj);
            }
        }
    }
    // Sort columns (rows are ordered by construction)
    sort(markedColumns.begin(),markedColumns.end());
    // Eliminate duplicates
    markedRows.erase   (unique(markedRows.begin()   ,markedRows.end())   ,markedRows.end()   );
    markedColumns.erase(unique(markedColumns.begin(),markedColumns.end()),markedColumns.end());

    // Construct COO matrix format
    vector<size_t> irow;
    vector<size_t> icol;
    vector<int>    val;        
    for (size_t ii = 0; ii < M; ++ii) {
        for(size_t jj = 0; jj < N; ++jj) {
            if ( ( find(markedRows.begin()   ,markedRows.end()   ,ii) == markedRows.end()    ) &&
                 ( find(markedColumns.begin(),markedColumns.end(),jj) == markedColumns.end() )
                ) {
                  irow.push_back(ii);
                  icol.push_back(jj);
                  val.push_back (matrix[ii][jj]);
                }
        }
    }    
    // FROM HERE YOU NO LONGER NEED MATRIX, AND YOU CAN FREE THE STORAGE

    // Print non zero entries
    for( size_t ii = 0; ii < irow.size(); ++ii) {
      cout << "A["<<irow[ii]<<","<<icol[ii]<<"] = "<<val[ii]<<endl;   
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your algorithm without allocating and auxiliary row or column by searching the matirx for a row that contains no zeros and a column that contains no zero elements.

If either of these searches fails, then the resulting matrix will all zeros, so your work is done by simply setting all elements to zero.

Otherwise, use the row and colum you found as the bookkeeping row and column you mentioned, setting the corresponding element to zero as you find zeros in the remainder of the matrix.  Once that pass is done you walk the bookkeeping row, setting the matix columns to zeros for any zero found in the bookkeeping row, similarly for the aux column.

Comment: But the bookkeeping row and column are overwritten. How will you restore the original values?

Comment: The bookkeeping row and column only have elements overwritten with zeros in locations that will be overwritten with zeros in the end result (because a zero has been found in that column or row). So there's no need to retain the original values for those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm can do it in O(M*N) time and O(1) space : -

> 1. Find the max element in the matrix .
> 2. Mat[i][j] = max - Mat[i][j] for all (i,j)
> 3. Notice that Mat[i][j] will only have positive values.
> 4. Use negetive values as sentinels and Mat[i][j] = max as zeros.
> 5. Retrieve original values as Mat[i][j] = max - Mat[i][j]

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy answer:
 <2 nested loop> to search through all columns and rows  you find any cell = 0  through all column and set it to zeros  through all row and set it to zeros. let me know if it not clear to record video for it.

```
Int main()
{
//example matrix dimension rows(r=6) * columns (c=3)
int r = 6;
int c = 3;
int matrix[r][c];

for(int i=0; i<r; ++i){
    for(int j=0 ; j < c ; ++j){
        if(matrix[i][j] == 0){ 
            for(int ii=0; ii<r; ++ii){
                Matrix[ii][j] = 0 ;
            }
            for(int jj=0; jj<c; ++jj){
                Matrix[i][jj] = 0 ;
            }
       }
   }  
}
}
```

Comment: @SteveFest  <2 nested loop> to search through all columns and rows <if> you find any cell = 0  <first loop> through all column and set it to zeros <second loop> through all row and set it to zeros. let me know if it not clear to record video for it.

Comment: You don't need a video, but **edit** your post: put the description in the **answer**, not in the **comment**, please.